# Moderna vs Pfizer booster

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, research

What published studies exist to support the choice of Moderna or Pfizer booster? The only study I could very quickly find is below. The study seems a bit preliminary, exactly as it says on the tin. I do not want to start flame wars by listing its caveats, just looking for any other, preferably peer-reviewed, evidence out there.
https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.10.10.21264827v2

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for studies supporting one or the other over *not getting a booster*? Or studies comparing the two and saying "Moderna is a better booster than Pfizer" or "Pfizer is better than Moderna"? If the latter, that preprint is the best you're going to get right now as far as I'm aware, and I don't think it's reasonable to expect a more definitive answer.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for the comment. Assuming here that one is only comparing two options: Moderna booster and Pfizer booster. No booster is considered a frame challenge. I am not looking for evidence for anything related to no booster.

Comment: Ok, then yeah, I think that preprint is the best available evidence right now, which suggests that both mRNA vaccine boosters are highly effective and that there isn't strong evidence in favor of one over the other (indeed, as they state they have not designed a large enough study to even attempt to answer that question)

Comment: @BryanKrause The best or the only evidence? Other evidence is welcome even if not as high quality. Feel free to post an answer even if the answer is: none at the moment.

Comment: It's hard to post such an answer within the guidelines of this site, unfortunately, because absence of evidence doesn't come with a citation. Logically, though, no one is going to have any booster efficacy data because widely available boosters are pretty new and it'll take months to have any such estimate, even if a study was started as soon as possible. There is secondary endpoint stuff like this preprint but that's it.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your comment and explanations!

Comment: Fairly related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/29169/did-the-nih-study-find-moderna-moderna-gave-more-antibodies-than-moderna-pfize People (esp. journalists, twitteratti) have tried to "mine" the limited data available, but it's mostly speculation and doesn't even rise to statistical (let alone clinical) significance. I think you've linked to the exact same study that is the topic of the previous Q.

Comment: @Fizz Thank you for the comment and the link to a great answer! Please post an answer here if you come across additional studies. I will make sure to upvote this too! :)